How to fix "Toppra failed to find the maximum path acceleration"
I'm using Drake's Toppra implementation to post-process a path produced by GcsTrajectoryOptimization. Things work fine until I put in acceleration limits.
grid_points = Toppra.CalcGridPoints(gcs_traj, CalcGridPointsOptions())
toppra = Toppra(gcs_traj, plant, grid_points)
toppra.AddJointVelocityLimit(velocity_lb, velocity_ub)

# uncommenting the line below sometimes leads to a crash!
# toppra.AddJointAccelerationLimit(accel_lb, accel_ub) 
   
toppra_times = toppra.SolvePathParameterization()

The error produced is ERROR:drake:Toppra failed to find the maximum path acceleration at knot 9/172.
I'm not sure why this would cause a failure. Empirically I've found that as I tighten acceleration limits, more trajectories fail to solve. This goes against my physical intuition, since one can always get a feasible solution by going sufficiently slowly.
What can I do to understand what is going wrong and how to fix it?
Updates
I have updated my code to try using Hung Pham's implementation and I've gotten some similar errors.
WARNING:toppra.algorithm.reachabilitybased.reachability_algorithm:A numerical error occurs: The controllable set at step [165 / 187] can't be computed.
WARNING:toppra.algorithm.reachabilitybased.reachability_algorithm:An error occurred when computing controllable velocities. The path is not controllable, or is badly conditioned.
WARNING:toppra.algorithm.algorithm:Fail to parametrize path. Return code: <ParameterizationReturnCode.FailUncontrollable: 'Error: Instance is not controllable'>

I've made sure that my path is differentiable up to order 2.
Here is a plot of the path first derivatives, each joint in a different color.

Here is a plot of the path second derivatives.

The problem clearly looks feasible and any acceleration and velocity bounds can be met by a trivial time dilation.

It looks like the discussion has moved to https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/21381 .

It seems like the problem is related to the leading and trailing flat segments in the first derivative profile. Any path retiming parameterization would have to blast through these regions infinitely fast in order to make progress.
As an aside, these leading and trailing flat solvers are generated by Drake's GcsTrajectoryOptimization solver traversing through a graph whose first and last vertices are Points, and then running NormalizeSegmentTimes on the resulting trajectory in preparation for Toppra. Trimming the leading and trailing segments from the trajectory before passing it into Toppra fixes the issue as far as I can tell.
